# Trying to subtract a variable from each element of an array

Tags: python-3.x

Hi i have a code that creates the price of a trip .I am trying to subtract a variable from each element of one of the array. In order to get the amount left to pay

```
pricepaidpp = []
namepeoplecoming = []
amountlefttopaypp = []

extrapeoplecount = 0  
moneycollected = 0
peoplecount = 0 
numofextrapeople = 0
totalpeoplecoming = numofpeople + Numofcarersneeded
moneypaidcalc = 00


while True:
    entry = input('Enter Name of people coming  ')
    moneyentry = input ('How much has he paid ')

    if peoplecount >= numofpeople : #breaks loop when number of people 
    reached 
    break



namepeoplecoming.append(entry) #adds the name the user  to the array 

pricepaidpp.append(moneyentry)  #adds how much the user has paid to the array 

pricepaidpp = list(map(int, pricepaidpp)) #turn strings in array to integers 

moneyentry = list(map(int, pricepaidpp)) 

amountlefttopaypp.append(moneyentry)

peoplecount = (peoplecount + 1 ) #adds one to the count 

moneycollected = sum(pricepaidpp)   #adds values of the array to get the total money paid 

amountlefttopaypp = [x-costpp for x in amountlefttopaypp]

#need code to minus price per person from amountlefttopaypp
```

whenever i try somthing i get typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list

Comment: Can you show what you tried that's getting the error?

Comment: amountlefttopaypp = [x-costpp for x in amountlefttopaypp]

Comment: You'll want to edit that into the question, along with an explanation of where `costpp` came from.

Comment: costpp is a variable in the beginning of the program didn't want to paste it because its long